# Change jmeter http client

Tags: apache, jmeter, performance-testing, apache-httpclient-4.x

The latest http client version that current jmeter (2.13) has is httpclient-4.2.6. How can I replace, or add the latest http client available from apache, HttpClient 4.4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the older httpclient jars from JMeter's lib directory and replace them with newer ones.

I had to do this today, attempting to install JMeterPlugins-WebDriver-1.2.1, as this plugin package contained newer httpclient versions. You can't leave the older ones and the new ones both in the lib directory.

To get the latest httpclient jars:
http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.httpcomponents%22%20AND%20a%3A%22httpclient%22

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will give just a bit more detail in case any one wants to do the same thing. The jars to be replaced are httpclient-{v}.jar, httpcore-{v}.jar and httpmime-{v}.jar, where {v} is the latest version. The links are:
http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.httpcomponents%22%20AND%20a%3A%22httpclient%22
http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.httpcomponents%22%20AND%20a%3A%22httpcore%22
http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.httpcomponents%22%20AND%20a%3A%22httpmime%22